# Handling html special character while Parsing html string using c#

Tags: c#, regex, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am using htmlagility pack to parse html string, and convert certain patterns to links.

Given a html string and a pattern "mystring". I have to replace the occurrence of this pattern in the hrml string with `<a href="/mystring.html>mystring</a>`. But there are two exceptions


1. I should not replace the pattern if it is already within an anchor tag, which means its immediate parent or any level parent should not be an anchor tag. For ex: `<a href="google.com><span>mystring</span><\a>` 
2. It should not be inside href. For ex `<a href="mystring">`.

- input string: `"<li><span>mystring test</span></li><li><a href='#'><span>mystring</span></li</li>"`
- expected output : `"<li><span><a href="/mystring.html>mystring</a> test</span></li><li><a href='#'><span>mystring</span></li</li>"`

I am using htmlagilitypack and loading this string as html doc and getting all text and looking whether its any level parent is not an anchor and replacing it. Everything worked simple and fine. But there is a problem here.

If my input string is something like `"li><span>mystring test < 10 and  5</span></li>"` there is a problem. Htmlagility parser considers the less than symbol as a html special character and considers the "< 10 and 5" as a html tag and produces something like this.

< 10="" and="" 5=""> (attributes with empty values).

IS there a work around for this using htmlagilityparser?
Should I take a step back and use regex? In that case how do I handle the any level anchor exception?
IS there a better approach for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `<` outside HTML tag is invalid. Use `&lt;` entity instead.

EDIT: If don't have control over input string, you may try replacing "< ":

```
inputhtml = inputhtml.Replace("< ", "&lt; ");
```

If there are any other errors, you can try importing MSHTML COM DLL. Reference COM dll  "Microsoft HTML object library".

Comment: I don't have control over the html input string. when this same html string is rendered in view it works fine. Why is the parser not able to differentiate? If I try to encode or do some processing to the input string then I end up changing all < to &lt; including those in proper html tags

Comment: have you tried heuristics like only replacing "<" followed by space? i mean if browsers render it correctly there must be some pseudo-criteria to decide whether it is a tag or not

Comment: I intially thought about this. But thought could be hacky. Tried couple of cases, looks fine for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. You could pre-clean the broken HTML so HtmlAgilityPack works better. This is possibly easier.
2. Or parse & track nested-structure of tags yourself, via a simple regex-based parser. But many HTML tags do not have to be normatively ended, such as `<TR> <TD> <P> <BR>`.. and you'll have to deal with the broken < angle-brackets here too.

Option 2) is not hard -- but will be more work first-off, for a payoff in improved reliability & control over how you handle "malformed" inputs from a low-quality source.